# Wordpress If file exists with page slug name show image else nothing, how does it looks like

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a php code in a wordpress widget called PHP Code Widget which only asks for proper enclosing:

All PHP code must be enclosed in the standard php opening and closing tags (  ) for it to be recognized and executed.

The code must use the current page title slug (i will use PAGES not posts) to look if in the upload folder there is any .jpg image named after the current page title SLUG. If there is such image, then it shows it:

As you can see it must also use current page title for the image alt. And if possible, to retrieve image height and width and put them in their html parts. However this last one is not a must as i can manually resize all images to the same size and leave those fixed.

So the more or less pseudo code would be something like:

php start
IF file exists uploads/current-page-slug.jpg
then

else
do nothing
php end

Ive read a bit about the wordpress loop, and im not sure if current page slug and current page title are reacheable from a sidebar widget.

Give me a hand please.

Comment: **I need to add a php code in a wordpress widget.** - I propose you *do not need* to do this, and in fact this is the wrong way to do this.  Write your own PHP in a plugin / theme file, **do not** use PHP Code Widget!

Comment: I agree with @cale_b. PHP Code Widget isn't the place to put this type of code, but it will work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you will need to get the slug of the current page and will want to put that into a variable:

```
$mySlug = basename(get_permalink());
```

I tend to use variables for path names in my code so, using your /uploads/ folder:

```
$myImgDir = "/uploads/"
$myImgFile = $myImgDir . $mySlug . ".jpg"
```

Two PHP functions we need require the server path instead of the URL so we need to make a third variable for that:

```
$myImgFileLoc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $myImgFile;
```

Next we set up our conditional to see if the file exists:

```
if (file_exists($myImgFileLoc)) {
```

In order to get the image attributes, we will be using the getimagesize() function of PHP. This function reads the image file and loads various attributes into an indexed array. Index 0 and 1 contain the width and height respectively, but Index 3 actually contains a string that will provide HTML size attributes:

```
$myImgAttriburtes = getimagesize($myImgFileLoc);
$myImgSize = $myImgAttriburtes[3];
```

Since you would be using this outside of the Loop, you need to add the following to get the Page's ID:

```
 global $post;
```

Then we put it all together grabbing the page name to use for the alt attribute:

```
<img src="<?php echo $myImgFile; ?>" <?php echo $myImgSize; ?> alt="<?php echo get_the_title($post-ID); ?>">
```

So the whole thing would look like this:

```
<?php
   $mySlug = basename(get_permalink());
   $myImgDir = "/uploads/";
   $myImgFile = $myImgDir . $mySlug . ".jpg";
   $myImgFileLoc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $myImgFile;
   if (file_exists($myImgFileLoc)) {
      $myImgAttriburtes = getimagesize($myImgFileLoc);
      $myImgSize = $myImgAttriburtes[3];
      global $post;
   ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $myImgFile; ?>" <?php echo $myImgSize; ?> alt="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: As the other commenters have said, do NOT use this in PHP Code widget. Write your own file.

Comment: Not working. Where it should be the image this is the only source code: `</h3><div class="execphpwidget"></div> </aside></div>` which is the widget php wrapping. So apparently is not doing anything for some reason. Do you have any idea. Maybe it is evaluating to false because son path issue.

Comment: I tested it using a development copy of the 2015 Theme that WordPress ships with. My guess is that this is something the Exec PHP Widget is doing. I would suggest hard-coding that into the theme file itself or writing your own plugin with that code as a widget.